# Setting values of struct members in other functions

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, allocation

Let's say I have this struct:

```
    typedef struct Foo {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    } Foo;
```

Now, I made this initialization function that'll allocate memory for Foo, and preset values into my object, like this:

```
    void initializeFoo(Foo *foo) {
        foo = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
        foo->a=0;
        foo->b=15;
        foo->c=0;
    }
```

On top of Foo, let's say we made a C++ class called Display, so we can display Foo, on a screen.

```
     class Display {
          public:
              Display();

          private:
              Foo* foo;
     }
```

Inside of the Display constructor I use initializeFoo(foo) to initialize my values for foo, however the preset values I've set for foo aren't there.

I thought it could be a memory allocation problem. I made sure that Display was properly allocated with C++'s 'new'. However, I've been scratching my head at this all day.

It seems like the only reason why it isn't working is because I set those values in initializeFoo(). But, that doesn't make sense to me.

Anybody else have a better opinion as to what could be happening here?

Comment: Are you working with `C` or `C++` ? Because what you have here looks like a very unhealthy blend.

Comment: @Matthieu I'm using C++ for my driver only. The other code must strictly be in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the `Foo` pointer by value to `initializeFoo` so can't modify the caller's pointer.  If you want this style of initializer, you'll need to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void initializeFoo(Foo **foo) {
    *foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    (*foo)->a=0;
    (*foo)->b=15;
    (*foo)->c=0;
}
```

In this case however, it'd be easier if you simply returned `Foo*` instead:

```
Foo *initializeFoo() {
    Foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    foo->a=0;
    foo->b=15;
    foo->c=0;
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant

```
void initializeFoo(Foo **foo) {
        *foo = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
        (*foo)->a=0;
        (*foo)->b=15;
        (*foo)->c=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Even pointers are passed by value  Like all out-parameters, they must be passed by either address (`&var`) or in C++, the parameter can be a reference-type (in this case a reference-to-pointer type). The latter of these is likely better, not to mention the smallest change:

Change this:

```
void initializeFoo(Foo *foo)
```

To this:

```
void initializeFoo(Foo*& foo) // <== note reference-to-pointer
```

That being said, this has no place in a good C++ program practicing well-define [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) methodologies. Read [this brief document](http://klmr.me/slides/modern%2Dcpp.pdf) on how you should not be using pointers to own resources in the first place. Ultimately your `foo` member should be a smart-pointer, if not an outright object instance.